# Protobuf: can changing the message name lead to backward compatibility error?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Suppose I have a the following Protobuf MessageData:

```
message Person {   
   string name = 1;
   int32 age = 2;
}
```

and I want to change the message name from "Person" to "PersonNew". If I only change protobuf version in the client, will the server may throw an error for an incompatibility error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you aren't using the `Any` type, message names don't exist in the data format, so you can change at will.